# How do I get an anchor button to fit inside a listed order tag?

Tags: php, css, wordpress-theming, html-lists, anchor

I have an anchor button that links to a contact page on a website. It is inside a listed item tag and it is stretching the header top and the listed item tag.  The anchor button currently looks like this:

```html
<li><div id="contact_us">
   <a href="/contact" class="red-bg" role="button">FREE Boiler Evaluation</a>
  </div></li>
```

The CSS for the anchor button currently looks like this:

```css
a.red-bg{
display: inline-block;
overflow:hidden;
padding: 0 10px;
}
```

But the CSS for the header looks like this:

```css
.header-top {
 background: #252525;
}
.header-top a {
 line-height: 40px;
}
.header-top .header-search a.red-bg {
 padding: 0 10px;
 display: block;
}
.header-top .container {
 position: relative;
}
.header-top ul li {
 list-style: none;
}
.header-top ul {
 margin: 0;
}
.header-top ul li, .header-search {
 float: left;
 margin-left: 25px;
}
.header-top ul li a {
 color: #f5f5f5;
 display: inline-block;
}
.header-top .red-bg {
 padding: 0 10px;
}
#header_wrapper ul.social-icons {
 float: right;
}
#header_wrapper ul.social-icons li {
 float: left;
 list-style: none;
 margin: 5px;
}
#header_wrapper ul.social-icons li a {
 background: url(img/social-icons.png) no-repeat;
 width: 27px;
 height: 30px;
 display: block;
 text-decoration: none;
}
#header_wrapper ul.social-icons li.facebook a {
 background-position: 0 -40px;
}
#header_wrapper ul.social-icons li.twitter a {
 background-position: -27px -40px;
}
#header_wrapper ul.social-icons li.linkedin a {
 background-position: -55px -40px;
}
#header_wrapper ul.social-icons li.blog a {
 background-position: -84px -40px;
}
#header_wrapper .pull-right ul {
 padding: 0 10px;
}
#header_wrapper ul.social-icons {
 display: none;
}
```

How do I get it to fit inside the listed item tag so that it doesn't keep stretching the header or the listed item tag?

Comment: I'm not certain what you're asking, but try removing the `overflow: hidden;`

Comment: what you need actuly?

Comment: I need the button to align with the search button on this website: http://ttifl.nexhorizon.net/

Comment: @HeatherWilkinsn if you want it to align then why give padding ?

Comment: `#contact_us {
    padding: 0px 20px 10px 20px;
    overflow: hidden;
}` change this in css of that page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a div inside the li so I made that a span, but your code doesn't include styling for that id so I'm pretty sure this will fix it. It's not semantically correct to have a block element inside an inline element.

See fix:

```css
.header-top {
 background: #252525;
}
.header-top a {
 line-height: 40px;
}
.header-top .header-search a.red-bg {
 padding: 0 10px;
 display: block;
}
.header-top .container {
 position: relative;
}
.header-top ul li {
 list-style: none;
}
.header-top ul {
 margin: 0;
}
.header-top ul li, .header-search {
 float: left;
 margin-left: 25px;
}
.header-top ul li a {
 color: #f5f5f5;
 display: inline-block;
}
.header-top .red-bg {
 padding: 0 10px;
}
#header_wrapper ul.social-icons {
 float: right;
}
#header_wrapper ul.social-icons li {
 float: left;
 list-style: none;
 margin: 5px;
}
#header_wrapper ul.social-icons li a {
 background: url(img/social-icons.png) no-repeat;
 width: 27px;
 height: 30px;
 display: block;
 text-decoration: none;
}
#header_wrapper ul.social-icons li.facebook a {
 background-position: 0 -40px;
}
#header_wrapper ul.social-icons li.twitter a {
 background-position: -27px -40px;
}
#header_wrapper ul.social-icons li.linkedin a {
 background-position: -55px -40px;
}
#header_wrapper ul.social-icons li.blog a {
 background-position: -84px -40px;
}
#header_wrapper .pull-right ul {
 padding: 0 10px;
}
#header_wrapper ul.social-icons {
 display: none;
}

a.red-bg{
display: inline-block;
background: red;
padding: 0 10px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
<li><span id="contact_us">
   <a href="/contact" class="red-bg" role="button">FREE Boiler Evaluation</a>
  </span></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: thanks. I am still not use to CSS so any help is gladly appreciated.

Comment: All good @HeatherWilkins! We are all learning CSS, it never stops. :)

Answer (score 0):

To say that you want `a` to fit inside `li` means you want a fixed `width` of `li`.

```css
a.red-bg {
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0 10px;
  border: 1px solid white
}

li {
  width: 100px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<li>
  <div id="contact_us">
    <a href="/contact" class="red-bg" role="button">FREE Boiler Evaluation</a>
    <a href="/contact" class="red-bg" role="button">FREE Boiler Evaluation</a>
    <a href="/contact" class="red-bg" role="button">FREE Boiler Evaluation</a>
    <a href="/contact" class="red-bg" role="button">FREE Boiler Evaluation</a>
    <a href="/contact" class="red-bg" role="button">FREE Boiler Evaluation</a>
    <a href="/contact" class="red-bg" role="button">FREE Boiler Evaluation</a>
  </div>
</li>
```

Comment: I appreciate the answer, but I know the CSS has an id called header-wrapper and two classes such as .pull-right and .header-top so I don't know if that would help with the CSS.